# Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr (measurement-1)

Tags: android

I tried almost everything, but I really don't know how to fix this one.

***A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf72195ce in tid 6243 (measurement-1)***

Maybe it's mistake of genymotion, but i really don't know. It's working fine on devices like Galaxy s5 (physical) api 21, s2(emulator) api 16. But when i try it on Nexus 4 or 5(emulator) api 22, Galaxy s6 (emulator) api 21, it will crash after 3 seconds.

Comment: Could you post more log about the backtrace? There must be more lines below `Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL)...`

Comment: No there is nothing bellow it. Just this. It does't crash on xamarin tho, so it must be genymotion.

Comment: ummm, it should have other information. Do you use IDE console to watch log? If so,  use `adb logcat -v time`  in command line instead, and see what happened around `Fatal signal 4`.

Comment: I have similar errors when I use google ads `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);` (commenting this line solves the problem).